# Repaint() in gameloop does'nt work

Tags: java, 2d, game-loop

Recently  I'm  working on a PAC-MAN clone.

I created  3 classes:

- **StartingClass** which extends `Jframe` and uses  `KeyListener`
- **Board** which  extends `Jpanel`
- **Sparx** which is responsible for changing the player's  sprite  coordinates.

The result is a frame with an unmoving image.

I changed  the  code  in various  ways  but  the  result  was  always  the  same (well sometimes even worse).

On zetcode.com,  kilobolt.com  and a  few  other  webpages I found some  source  code which works on some  other  concepts, but  still  I don't know how to fix my code.  I'm  sure  that  I'm missing something  obvious. Could you tell  me  what  is  wrong with my repaint  method?

Here's  my  sourcecode

StartingClass

```
public  class  StartingClass extends  JFrame  implements  KeyListener, Runnable{
public  StartingClass(){
       board=new  Board();

       add(board);

       sparx=new  Sparx();
}

public  static  void  main(String[]  args) {

       new  StartingClass();

}

@Override public  void keyPressed(KeyEvent  arg0) {

       switch(arg0.getKeyCode()){

       case  KeyEvent.VK_UP:

       sparx.moveUp(); break;

       case  KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:

       sparx.moveDown(); break;

       case  KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:

       sparx.moveLeft(); break;

       case  KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:

       sparx.moveRight(); break; }

}
@Override public  void  run()

{ while(true){

       sparx.update();

       board.repaint();

       try  { thread . sleep (17) ;

        }  catch  (InterruptedException  e)

       { //  TODO  Auto-generated catch block e.printStackTrace();

} 

}

}

}
```

Board

```
public  class  Board extends  JPanel{

       Sparx sparx;

       public  Board(){

              sparx=new  Sparx();

}

@Override public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

       g.drawImage(sparx.getSparx(),  sparx.getSparxX(),  sparx.getSparxY(), null);

 }

}
```

Comment: Please format your questions! If they're not easy to read then they won't attract answers.

Comment: Are you calling Init() or starting your Runnable thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The is no problem with your repaint() method. The problem here is that the Sparx you update and move is a different Sparx then the one you render/paint. In your Board class you create a new Sparx instance and this is the one you render out. This is a different instance from the one you create in your StartingClass and update the position of.

Simply overwrite the Sparx stored in the Board class with the one in the StarterClass class or pass it through the Board constructor when you create the Board.